# How can I disable the notification sounds while playing music?

Tags: settings, notifications, music

I don't like the notification sounds overlaying my music playback, but I can't find any setting to disable notification sounds while playing music.

I also don't like the way the sound overlay works. The IPhone handles this much better.

Is there any way to set this up to behave more like the Iphone or turn off the notifications while playing music at all?

Comment: what about for specific apps? suppressing the apps which are just annoying?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First install Quick Settings: http://www.appbrain.com/app/quick-settings/com.bwx.bequick

With that under volume control you can control the following volumes seperately:

- ringer
- notification
- media (this would control the music)
- alarm
- voice
- system

On top of that you can install [Quick Profiles](http://www.appbrain.com/app/quick-profiles/de.softxperience.android.quickprofiles)

...which will let you create a sound profile with the settings you want and easily activate it with one click.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to download anything. Go into Settings and Volume, then turn off ring tone and notifications. Now, huzzah! Play music, still receive emails and messages but no irritating butt in of sounds!